# How to cluster indexed variables without creating a parameter for it in GLPK?

Tags: indexing, cluster-computing, glpk, mathprog

I have the following problem on a MLP.

I want to cluster some variables when they have the same value, for example
a[i]=a[i(1..i]], which will mean cheking the variables that are the same.
That would be the initial if condition.

EX: a[2]=3; a[4]=3 -> The condition for this two variables will be true.

Later, if that condition is true, I want to add the follwing:

D[i]=D[i]+D[1..i], for those i that are true on the previous condition.

Ex: D[2]=D[2]+D[4].

The problem is that since overwrite the new value of D[2] ,GLPK does not solve the optimal model anymore, which lead me to wonder if it is possible to clustering indexed variables without creating a new one, and in case it is not, what could be a solution.

Many thanks for your help, .